# Searchview overlap problem with Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I have a ConstraintLayout, and one RecyclerView and SearchView in it.
The problem is, when I click SearchButton for write somethings, RecycleView is overlapping on it.

I connect the dots between them, and tried different things but the result is always same.
How can I prevent to overlap it?

[image: Before Click]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <SearchView
        android:background="@color/colorGray"
        android:id="@+id/mySearchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/myRecycleView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mySearchView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.466" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with these simple constraints

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/mySearchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/dark_gray"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecycleView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mySearchView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Lakhwinder, ufortunately still same result, it's overlapping.

Comment: Updated the answer, please check

Answer (score 1):

Remove `app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/myRecycleView"` from your `SearchView`

and add `app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` in your `SearchView`

Try this

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/mySearchView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/myRecycleView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/myRecycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mySearchView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Output**

[image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your constraints layout.

```
 <SearchView
    android:id="@+id/mySearchView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/myRecycleView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mySearchView"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Elevation to search view.

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

or you can use

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mySearchView"
```

**Note**: Change height to 0dp

Comment: Hi Mohan, this time Searchview overlapping on RecyclerView:) By the way there is already "app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mySearchView" line. I don't get what you suggest with this line?

Comment: @sleepy in your code you added app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mySearchView"

but you forgot to change height to 0dp instead you was using wrap_content

Comment: sorry about that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Use Reletive Layout and paste search-view xml  code after recyclerview.it will solve your problem because in reletivelayout items that comes at end always remain on top of the other